# .htaccess RewriteRule without URL change in browser i waht url like www.xyx.com/habdy/larry-ness--sports-handicapper-review

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite my URLS

From:

```
www.xyx.com/habdy/larry-ness
www.xyx.com/habdy/Demo-test
www.xyx.com/habdy/Demo-from
```

To:

```
www.xyx.com/habdy/larry-ness-sports-handicapper-review
www.xyx.com/habdy/Demo-test-sports-handicapper-review
www.xyx.com/habdy/Demo-from-sports-handicapper-review
```

I tried the following rule, but it did not work

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^larry-ness(/.*|)$ /larry-ness-sports-handicapper-review$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: _without URL change in browser_ - it is impossible only using RewriteRule

Comment: i had try like this but it's not work

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^larry-ness(/.*|)$ /larry-ness-sports-handicapper-review$1 [L,NC]

Comment: So you want to show additional `-sports-handicapper-review` to your clients? Can you clarify?

Comment: @anubhava Yes i want to append -sports-handicapper-review

Comment: ok what happens now if you enter `www.xyx.com/habdy/Demo-from-sports-handicapper-review` in browser?

Comment: @anubhava I have 5 different 2 urls and i need to add "-sports-handicapper-review" common string for all five urls .

Comment: Thank You , 
I have resolve using

    RewriteBase /handy/
    RewriteRule  ^larry-ness-sports-handicapper-review/?$ larry-ness.html [NC,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `/handy/.htaccess` you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /handy/

RewriteRule ^(\w-]+)-sports-handicapper-review/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```